# How to make Grid lines visible in SWT Grid Layout?

Tags: java, swt, grid-layout, gridlines

I want to know how to make the Grid lines visible in SWT Grid Layout. I can arrange widgets in a grid layout. But now I want to make those grid lines visible. So then it would be just like a table. Is there any way to do that? Note-I don't want to use a table for this, because by using a table too it seems that making cell borders visible is impossible when widgets are included inside table cells-([How to set lines visible in SWT table, including widgets in cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270276/how-to-set-lines-visible-in-swt-table-including-widgets-in-cells/26278098#26278098))

Comment: if you set border to component inside grid ,it will appear like a table

Comment: So it has to set for each component and seems rather difficult. Anyway I tried to set a border to a Label but not succeeded. how to do that??

Comment: `GridLayout` is just a layout it never draws anything. You could perhaps do something with lots of `Composite` objects with `SWT.BORDER`.

Comment: Using lots of composite objects is really cumbersome for a table with lots of cells..!!!

Comment: Check here (duplicate post?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444004/how-do-we-show-the-gridline-in-gridlayout